# Concatenate dictionary keys to a string

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 14 dictionaries all containing the same keys of information (i.e. time, date etc.) , but varying values. I'm trying to build a function that will put together a sentence when the dictionary is listed as the argument in the function.

If I have a dictionary:

```
dic1 = {'Name': 'John', 'Time': 'morning'}
```

And I want to concatenate them to a string:

```
print 'Hello ' + dic1['Name']+', good ' + dic1['Time']+ '.'
```

How would I go about this?

*Note, sorry, this returns the error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Comment: You want to concatenate keys or values?>

Comment: I want the value by calling the key. The dic[] is an error, it should say say dic1[]

Comment: This code does work without any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using new style string formatting (python2.6 or newer):

```
print("Hello {Name}, good {Time}.".format(**dic1))
```

As for your error, I can't explain it with the code you've provided above.  If you try to `__add__` a string to a list, you'll get that error:

```
>>> [45,3] + "foo"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

But adding a list to a string (which is what you would be doing with the example code if your dictionary had a list as a value) gives a slightly different error:

```
>>> "foo" + [45,3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you mean *interpolate*, not *concatenate*.

```
print "Hello %(Name)s, good %(Time)s" % dic1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
web_response = {2L: 67.0, 3L: 13.67, 4L: 10.25, 5L: 11.8, 6L: 11.83}
```

I've a dictionary named "web_response",For concatenation of **dictionary with string** I used **comma** ","

```
print "web_response=", web_response
```

**Output:**

```
web_response= {2L: 67.0, 3L: 13.67, 4L: 10.25, 5L: 11.8, 6L: 11.83}
```